# MySQL 8 InnoDB 32KB and 64KB page sizes benefits for HDD

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0, page-size

[MySQL page size documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_page_size) says:

> For releases up to and including MySQL 5.5, the size of each InnoDB
>   page is fixed at 16 kilobytes. This value represents a balance: large
>   enough to hold the data for most rows, yet small enough to minimize
>   the performance overhead of transferring unneeded data to memory.
>   Other values are not tested or supported.
>
> Starting in MySQL 5.6, the page size for an InnoDB instance can be
>   either 4KB, 8KB, or 16KB, controlled by the innodb_page_size
>   configuration option. As of MySQL 5.7.6, **InnoDB also supports 32KB and**
>   **64KB** page sizes. For **32KB and 64KB** page sizes, ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
>   is not supported and the maximum record size is 16KB.

and then

> Smaller page sizes can help performance with storage devices that use
>   small block sizes, particularly for SSD devices in disk-bound
>   workloads, such as for OLTP applications. As individual rows are
>   updated, less data is copied into memory, written to disk,
>   reorganized, locked, and so on.

How about using higher (32KB or 64KB) page size than the default 16KB?
In what case should you do that and what you get as a benefit?

I will be setting up a new MySQL instance with traditional HDD and I was wondering if changing default 16KB could have impact on performance, efficiency of storage utilization.

So far I only found a drawback of using 32KB and 64KB page size:

> For 32KB and 64KB page sizes, ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED is not supported
>   and the maximum record size is 16KB.

Comment: If you're so concerned about performance, then why are you using an HDD?

Comment: @Bill Karwin just have it and need to stick with it. Too much data that exceeds budget if SSD considered.

Comment: Well, you really should load-test your data with your query traffic to be sure. There's no way someone can guess what the performance difference will be. There might be no significant difference. Probably defining the right indexes to support your queries will have much more benefit than you can ever get by choosing a different page size.

Comment: @BillKarwin True, that's at the end the real answer to the question, but was just curious why they put 32KB and 64KB option and I think I found 2 reasons: [(...) For example, a maximum InnoDB page size of 64KB with a 4KB file system block size may improve compression...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-page-compression.html) due to "For example, if innodb_page_size=16K and the file system block size is 4K, page data must compress to less than or equal to 12K to make hole punching possible." Second: deploying MySQL at filesys. that already is set 32 or 64KB so both match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people hit the **max row size** of about 8000 bytes.  Switching to 32KB pages doubles that limit.  However, switching to 64KB does not go past 16KB limit.

Since InnoDB blocks tend to be **scattered** around the disk, having bigger blocks will save slightly in arm motion on a HDD.  I would expect this to be only **single-digit percentage improvement**.  And it would vary depending on the type of activity.  A freshly loaded table may show no improvement; a table with a lot of churn may show some.

If your dataset fits in the **buffer_pool**, then there is not much I/O to be done, so the block size does not come into play much.

The cost of **arm motion** is somewhat minimized by drivers or controllers that optimizer the order of disk operations.  RAID with a cache does an especially good job, and it can make writes virtually instant.  "Hole punching" probably adds to the frequency of arm motion.  Classic tradeoff:  "speed versus space".

If your dataset is **too large** to fit in RAM, and if you do a lot of "point queries", then a *smaller* block size would be better.  But if you do a lot of table (or index) scans, then a larger block size has a slight benefit.

Keep in mind that *all* the data must use the same blocksize.

Of the thousands of forum Question I have seen, I don't think any changed the blocksize.  You will be in uncharted waters.

Also note that, while **`ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`** saves some disk space, it chews up some RAM -- this is because some (all?) blocks are kept in RAM both compressed and uncompressed.

The numbers I have seen for that row_format is only 50%.  Any decent compression algorithm compresses virtually any sort of text by about 2/3.  So, if I am tempted to use compression, I compress the compressible columns (eg `TEXT`, but not jpgs), and do it in the *client*, thereby offloading the CPU effort from the server.  I believe (without any hard evidence) that this is a **better way** to compress your data.  Also, I almost never use `BIGINT`.

(Everything I say here is **theoretical**, based either in very limited MySQL documentation or the principles of HDDs.)

I have a **Rule of Thumb** for optimizations.  "If the back-of-envelope calculations estimate less than 10% improvement, then move on -- look for something else to optimize."

So, I say "move on".

Comment: Indeed — there are exceptions to every rule of course, but the way to know if an exception applies to a given app is **to load-test that app.**

Answer (score 0):

Bigger DB block size reduces index tree height = less I/O
Everything in InnoDB is an index. So the benefit should be noticeable. Even more so for HDD.
I just migrated a 150GB db from Percona 5.1 to 5.7 via dump/load changing DB block size to 64kB. The server has 128GB of RAM, so there are nearly zero reads, but I still expect performance gains on backups, less disk writes, faster shutdown/startup.
The only important consideration about bigger DB Block Size is having enough RAM and giving InnoDB that much RAM to cache. A Block Size 4x as large means the cache will contain 1/4 as many DB blocks which could in some extreme cases lead to more reads due to cache trashing.